# how to add ascii character in listview?

Tags: c#, listview, ascii

I want to add ascii char in my listview.
Here is my code:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
item.Text = Convert.ToString(count);
item.SubItems.Add(imgList.imgName.Substring(0, imgList.imgName.Length - 3));
item.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(imgList.score));
if (Util.FNameExtraction(addImage.FileName).Substring(0, 5) == imgList.imgName.Substring(0, 5))
{
    // ASCII should place
}

LvResultList.Items.Add(item);
```

I tried several types but could not find any solution.

Here is what i tried:

```
item.Text = Convert.ToString(char(195)) ;
item.Text = 195;
item.Text = 195.ToString();
item.SubItems.Add(195);
item.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(char(195));
item.SubItems.Add(195.ToString());
```

But all my attempts failed. Could you give me an idea about how to add ***ASCII*** here?

Comment: 195 isn't in the ASCII range. Which character are you actually interested in?

Comment: @JonSkeet I want to add Tick.. Here is table http://4toc.com/fb/FBHelp/gfx/AppF_ASCIITable.png

Comment: tRY..... 
Convert.ToChar("195")

Comment: @HassanNisar i does not allows me to convert char.It gives Error

Comment: @HassanNisar: That's really not going to help...

Comment: @Jon Skeet .. Thank you for correction. Your answer explains it all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

195 is not in the ASCII range. Unfortunately there are many sites around which show "ASCII tables" containing characters over 127. These are often called "extended ASCII" - often with a false implication that there's only *one* such encoding. .NET uses Unicode - and each `char` is a UTF-16 code unit. So `(char) 195` is actually [U+00C3](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/c3/index.htm), which is a "Latin capital A with a tilde".

The character you were looking at wasn't even a tick - it was a square root sign.

For an actual *tick*, I suggest you want [U+2713](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2713/index.htm), which you'd add like this:

```
item.SubItems.Add = "\u2713";
```

Of course, that relies on the font you're using supporting that character.

Comment: You are awesome.. Thank you very much. It should be change to item.SubItems.Add("\u2713") in order to place next coloum :)